# R: Whats the most efficient way to code this formula in R?

Tags: r, performance

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to code this formula in R. I can implement this using a loop. But thats not the most efficient.

Formula for the Efficiency Ratio Indicator :

```
ER = Direction / Volatility 
Direction = ABS (Close – Close[n])
Volatility = n ∑ (ABS(Close – Close[1]))
```

volatility is the sum of the absolute value of the last n price changes (Close – Prior Close)

n = look back period.Example: n=10

R code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
prices <- Ad(SPY)

ER <- function(prices, n=10)
{
   direction <- abs((prices - lag(prices,n)))
   volatility <- 
   efficiencyRatio <- direction/volatility
   return(efficiencyRatio)
}
```

I am looking for help to fill in "volatility" variable inside the ER function.

Thanks.

Comment: @lmo You are correct.. that was a typo... Correcting it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could calculate volatility as follows:

```
# silly example
y <- 1:10

volatility <- length(y) * sum(sapply(2:(length(y)), 
                                     function(i) abs(y[i]-y[i-1])))
```

You can break apart the function to see that `sapply(2:10, function(i) abs(y[i]-y[i-1]))` calculates 9 1s, which makes sense given the vector. Sum those up and multiple by the number of days.

If you want to extend this to a vector that is longer than n, to get a moving average, you can use

```
volatility <- function(y, n) {
                sapply((n+1):length(y), 
                  function(rollSpot) {
                     n * sum(sapply((rollSpot-(n-1)):rollSpot, 
                                    function(i) abs(y[i]-y[i-1])))
                  })
              }
```

The rollSpot variable indexes the moving average: how many periods are you looking back. The current implementation includes the current period and the previous n-1 periods. If you want to include the previous n periods, you can decrement `(rollSpot-(n-1)):rollSpot` to `(rollSpot-n):(rollSpot-1)`.

Comment: Thanks @lmo. I am trying to understand the "rollSpot-9" part. Shouldn't the reference be to n-1 instead of 9. I will run through the code see whats going on. But, this definitely gets me going in the right direction.

Comment: @CyberStudent Oops, that -9 should be a -(n-1). I'll change it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package to apply your function in a rolling window of length `n`.

Below is an example using just the `direction` portion of your code. You can, of course, expand the `direction` function in the code below to include the rest of your calculations.

```
library(zoo)

roll.direction = function(dat, n) {

  # The function to apply
  direction = function(x) {
    abs(x[length(x)] - x[1])
  }

  # Apply the function to dat in a rolling window of length n
  rollapply(dat, width=n, FUN=direction)
}
```

Now run the function on your data:

```
roll.direction(as.numeric(prices[,1]), 10)
```